# What is the 'Deconfliction Service'?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, caa-uk-regulations, uk

> **High Speed Flights**
>
> 2.36 - When receiving an ATS surveillance service, certain ex-military aircraft types have been granted a CAA exemption from the
>   Air Navigation Order requirement to fly at an IAS less than 250 kt
>   below Flight Level
>   100. In order to alert the controller to this higher speed profile, pilots of exempted aircraft shall, on initial contact, prefix the
>   aircraft callsign with ‘FASTJET’ or ‘FASTPROP’ (depending on
>   propulsion type), e.g. “Kennington Radar, FASTJET G-ABCD request
>   Deconfliction service”.
>
> Use of this prefix shall be confined to initial contact with ATC
>   agencies for periods of flight during which operations at airspeeds in
>   excess of 250 kt are intended. Once acknowledged, it will not normally
>   be necessary for pilots to use the prefix in subsequent transmissions
>   until making initial contact with other ATSUs.

Source: Manual of Radiotelephony, Edition 2016

What is meant by Deconfliction Service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A deconfliction service is a specific type of air traffic service.

Normally, outside of controlled airspace, air traffic controllers do not alert pilots of potential encounters with other aircraft (conflicts).

However, there my be other services offered outside of controlled airspace, typically these are Flight Information Services (FIS).

In the UK, four air traffic services are distinguished outside controlled airspace: Basic Service, Traffic Service, Deconfliction Service and Procedural Service

> A **Basic Service** is an ATS provided for the purpose of giving advice
>   and information useful for the safe and efficient conduct of flights.
>   This may include weather information, changes of serviceability of
>   facilities, conditions at aerodromes, general airspace activity
>   information, and any other information likely to affect safety. The
>   avoidance of other traffic is solely the pilot’s responsibility.

<sub>source: [UK Flight Information Services CAP 774, February 2015](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP%20774Issue2_3.pdf)</sub>

Note the last sentence.

The deconfliction service is defined as:

> A **Deconfliction Service** is a surveillance based ATS where, in
>   addition to the provisions of a Basic Service, the controller provides
>   specific surveillance-derived traffic information and issues headings
>   and/or levels aimed at achieving planned deconfliction minima, or for
>   positioning and/ or sequencing. However, the avoidance of other
>   traffic is ultimately the pilot’s responsibility

Again, note the last sentence.